# Movie with a completely irrelevant opening scene, where a dead old man eats soup

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have recently watched the film and read the trivia from IMDb, but i can't remember the title of the movie.

The movie, that i am referring has an opening scene, completely irrelevant to the movie. A man comes home, talking his wife about an older man. And she is terrified, because she knows that the old man is dead. After that the old man comes to their house and eats soup then leaves. Then the real movie begins.

On the trivia, the director replied to a question about the opening scene; it was not related to movie, but was just to get attention of the audience.
Which movie was this that?

Comment: Language? How recently did you watch it? Where (TV, cinema)? Color or B&W? Try to add as much information as possible.

Comment: Also, have you checked your Internet History?

Comment: i am not 100 percent sure but the movie was english and the opening scene was non-english. how recently is irrelevant about the question, i may watched 1950s movie in 2017

Comment: yes i doublechecked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the scene you are talking about

It's from the movie [*A Serious Man* (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1019452/)

> The Coen Brothers stated that the opening scene was nothing more than a little short that they made up to get the audience in the proper mood, and that there is no meaning behind it.